# Recommened way to ensure Raspberry Pi connectivity

Tags: raspbian, wifi, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os

what's the recommended way to ensure connectivity throughout the time?

I'm using wifi in this case, on a Raspberry PI 4 w/ Raspbian 10 buster.

I noticed that it's losing connectivity randomly after some time. It seems there's some idle-timeout config, as I reboot and got reconnected successfully. Another guess I tried earlier was to run `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure` and it worked like a charm as well. So I'm thinking to use a cron job to run it periodically, what do you think guys?

Thanks

Comment: "it's loosing (sic) connectivity randomly after some time" how do you know?   wpa_cli is a text-based frontend program for interacting with wpa_supplicant so by **brute force** will restart wpa_supplicant, but `dhcpcd` already does this.

Comment: @Milliways: Methinks that comment would be a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Milliways - losing* thanks - so are you suggesting to restart dhcpcd, creating a cronjob to run `sudo service dhcpcd restart`? And do you know any config that would affect the wifi connection, maybe? Thanks

Comment: *"I noticed that it's losing connectivity randomly after some time"* -> You may want to explain exactly how you determine that, as it may just **seem** to be so, in which case the problem is a bit different.

Comment: "are you suggesting to …" the ONLY thing I suggest is that you explain your problem **BEFORE** trying to fix it. I have several Pi running - they run for months without problem. It is more likely that some connection times out.

Comment: wpa_supplicant is very robust. It will reconnect by itself if it loose a connection. So using a cron job is only to "fix" a symptom not the problem.

Comment: Right, so let's dig into the problem first - basically, I have SSH/VNC and after some time when I try to connect into the Pi it doesn't respond, although if I plug a monitor it says it's connected, that's the symptom. I tested rebooting and running wpa_cli, both cases worked. In your opinion, how can I diagnose or explain better to give you more info? Thanks

Comment: Why not troubleshoot it as a basic lack of internet problem? ping the TCP address and post the results. If it pings, I would then want to see the output of ssh -vv user@piaddress

Comment: When it happened `ping` was the first thing I've tried, and I got a timeout...